# Множественная выборка с помощью выпадающего списка select2

Tags: php, yii2, список, выборка, множества

Здравствуйте товарищи,

Проблема вот в чем: пытаюсь с помощью выпадающего списка kartik select2 сделать множественную выборку получателей письма таким образом:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->widget(Select2::classname(),
    [ 'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),
        'options' =>
            ['placeholder' => 'Select receivers...', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' =>
            [ 'tags' => true,
                'maximumInputLength' => 10
            ],
    ]);
?>
```

Но при нажатии кнопки "Send" под текстовым полем Receiver ID выводит красным ошибку "Receiver ID must be an integer".

Пожалуйста объясните как правильно использовать этот список или же предоставьте альтернативные решения.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вы уверены, что при множественном выборе тип поля в базе должен быть `int`? Может всё-таки `string`?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы одно и тоже письмо отправлялось нескольким пользователям, т.е. запись дублировалась для разных receiver_id. Разве если я поменяю тип поля на string это решит мою проблему?

Comment: Да, если получившийся массив  вы будете перебирать при отправке писем

Comment: Можете привести пример такого перебора?

Comment: Обычный цикл же, попробуйте так `foreach($model->receiver_id as $user_id) {
                                    echo $user_id.'<br />';
                                }`. Если данный цикл выводит id юзеров, которым нужно отправить письмо, то дальше нужно просто прикрутить логику отправки письма и добавить в этом цикл остальные повторяющие данные из модели.

Comment: Мне кажется предложенный вами вариант создаст в базе данных одну запись, с несколькими значениями через запятую в колонке receiver_id, я прав?

Comment: предложенный вариант создаст запись с теми данными, которые вам выдаёт виджет, а вы хотите несколько записей делать?

Comment: должно создаваться несколько записей с одинаковыми данными, но разными id и receiver_id, т.е. одно и то же письмо должно отображаться у нескольких получателей

Comment: тогда вам нужно поле, которое не будет входить в эту модель, перебираете массив в контроллере через цикл, внутри цикла будет создание строки с текущим значением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы правильная ошибка. У вас же айдишник hasOne а не hasMany

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiverIDs')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select receivers...', 
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [ 
            'tags' => true,
            'maximumInputLength' => 10,
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

И в моделе

```
class Model extends base\ActiveRecord {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            //....
            ['receiverIDs', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']]
        ];
    }

    public $receiverIDs = [];

}
```

Непомню уже как Select2 с данными настройками сохраняет. Либо через запятую как строку тогда нужно `explode(',' , $this->receiverIDs)` либо как массив айдишников. Посмотрите что формируется в запросе